# CoreData validateValue: forKey:

Tags: ios, validation, core-data

I am trying to use validatevalue:forkey: method to validate a coredata property.

I have a textfield that I am getting a string from I then want to check that string against my validation.

I am assuming that it is attempting to validate against the Reg. Exp. I have in my model.

However, no matter what I input it will always pass the validation.

EDIT:

The regular expression is a standard regular expression for validating email.

I can post some "official" code tomorrow, but its basically like the following:

```
NSString *string = textfield.text;

if(![myEntity validateValue:&string forKey:@"email"])
{
    // provide necessary user feed back i.e. let user know email is not in valid format}
}
```

Comment: Please include some code, and the details of the reg ex from your object model.

Comment: Also I did find this: http://openradar.appspot.com/10666148 so I guess im not the only one with this issue

Comment: You should be able to get this to work - If you have multiple validations in place you may have the same situation as in the linked bug, otherwise there may be some other problem. I look forward to seeing the official code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure `validatevalue:forKey`: is what you want.  This is what the validation should look like:

```
- (BOOL)validateEmail:(id *)value error:(NSError **)error {
    if (self.email && ![self.email isValidEmailAddress]) {
        if( error )        
             *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"MyErrorDomain" code:1];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Note that `isValidEmailAddress` doesn't actually exist. :-)

Comment: Thanks. I did end up implementing my own version of validation. I just assumed that because coredata included a regular expression field in the model it would automatically check against it with the validation statement I had originally posted.

Comment: validateValue:forKey:error: should work without any custom code if there are constraints in place in the managed object model.

Comment: validateValue:forKey:error: will call methods that fit the patter validate<Key>:error:.

Answer (score 0):

The [NSPredicate documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html) specifies that Cocoa uses [ICU](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp) regular expressions for predicates - and this is what Core Data uses for regex-based validation. This means that many regular expressions you find on the internet may not work correctly without modification. You should test your regular expression with a tool that allows ICU regular expressions. A non-ICU regular expression is the most common reason that a regular expression validation rule will appear to not execute, or it will pass when it should not.

Core Data evaluates validation rules specified in the managed object model before custom validation methods (that follow the pattern `validate<Key>:error:`. An empty implementation of one of these methods that returns YES can be useful for troubleshooting validation problems.